# SQL Error: 1036 - Illegal Variable

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I keep getting `SQL Error: 1036 - illegal variable name/number` but I am not sure why.

The database has all of the following fields, spelled exactly the same and the form inputs do too. I tried deleting them one by one to find which would be the "illegal variable" but it doesn't seem to like any of them.

```
case 'DATABASE':

$args[] = array('database_work_location', $in['database_work_location']);
$args[] = array('previous_work_point', $in['previous_work_point']);
$args[] = array('requested_due_date', $in['requested_due_date']);
$args[] = array('unit_request', $in['unit_request']);
$args[] = array('primary_purpose_descr', $in['primary_purpose_descr']);

$DB->query("
    INSERT INTO request_database
    (
    database_work_location
    ,previous_work_point
    ,requested_due_date
    ,unit_request
    ,primary_purpose_descr
    ) 
    VALUES (
    :database_work_location
    ,:previous_work_point
    ,TO_DATE(:requested_due_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
    ,:unit_request
    ,:primary_purpose_descr
    )
    "
    ,$args
    );
break;
```

Comment: did the below solve the problem @navlag?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I added the missing code to the question description above. Please let me know if you see anything funny. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PHP, but don't you need to parse the statement if you want to use bind variables? Looks like it's trying to treat `:unit_request` as a name rather than a bind, perhaps, but not sure. Also looks like you're replacing `$args` with each assignment, but again not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
You missed the semi-Colon at the end.TRy this

INSERT INTO request_database
(
database_work_location
,previous_work_point
,requested_due_date
,unit_request
,primary_purpose_descr
) 
VALUES 
(
:database_work_location
,:previous_work_point
,TO_DATE(:requested_due_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
,:unit_request
,:primary_purpose_descr
);
```

Comment: The ';' was in the PHP, I updated the code above, but it's not working.